# Should I use null or a separate table?

Tags: database-design

I could have a nullable field or I could do basic normalisation, having another table which may or may not join to a row in this table.

My instinct was to use the second method, as this is the "right" (normalised) way of handling this. However, thinking about this, it can have drawbacks.

- The whole entity is not easily visible in its table (you have to - first find and then - jump to its linking tables)
- you now have to remember to join the table(s)
- It could lead to loads and loads of tables (I don't know if this is an issue for performance)

What do you usually do? It it worth creating a new table just to have an optional property for an entity?

Comment: The question is interesting but abstract and vague. Can you give a concrete example of the problem you want to solve ...

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind This is a general question. A table with an optional field

Comment: An optional field is just a column that can be NULL. I see no reason to have a separate table for that - unless there are very specific and measurable issues with performance. Like one mention was a "long" field - one that contains, say, a user's resume or photograph. If 90% of the queries do not use those columns, then it might make sense to separate them out. However most of database systems store those out-of-line anyway, in dedicated data structures (CLOB or BLOB).

Comment: So, again, unless there is an actual measurable problem in keeping information together, then I would advise against introducing more tables just based on theory and "best practices". It will make queries more complex by introducing unnecessary joins, and may bring performance questions.

Comment: Also putting something in a separate table is not normalization. It would be if you had cases like this: a column with a country code and one with the country name. That is a possibility for normalization: retain the country code, and introduce a separate table with country code and country name (and other country details like population, shape, currency etc).

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind There are different aspects to normalisation. A fully-normalised table does not contain null values.

Comment: A 1NF relation certainly allows nulls. Some higher NFs may prohibit nulls. But database design is primarily a practical exercise, and NULLs are rarely avoided. Consider a table of customers with columns TELEPHONE_NR, EMAIL, TWITTER_HANDLE. Clearly not all customers have those. Some may have a telephone nr, some have an email, some have a twitter handle. It is natural to allow null in those columns. A NULL TWITTER_HANDLE just means this customer does not have any.

Comment: The alternative of having three separate tables for storing those optional values would mean that each query to get full customer details would need to join four tables ? That will work - but the SQL will be much more complex, and most likely not as efficient as a simple table access. Not to mention changes (inserts, updates, deletions ...).

Comment: At some point, you have to sacrifice theoretical purity to practicality and ease of use. Denormalizing is a very common process when designing relational data models.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like all things, the answer is "it depends".

More tables <> bad if the tables are necessary for proper normalization.  Splitting nullable columns off is something I do often, but not always.  What factors into my decision are things like:

1. How often will the column be NULL? If it's rarely populated, may make sense to have it as an optional column, implemented as its own table.  This acts like a filtered index any time you might need to locate certain records.
2. What is the context of the optional column(s)?  If it's information you won't have until a later event occurs (shipping/payment info, etc), then logically it may make more sense for you to implement it separately from the parent table.
3. How will the data be accessed/how wide is the parent table?  I often deal with summary data from vendors that results in very wide tables with a lot of null values.  I usually will split each column into its own table in order to speed up ad hoc queries that only need a small subset of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I'll split the (optional description) column into a separate table